# apache <Location /test> exclude several IP addresses

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration

I have the following  configuration (beside a ReverseProxy entry) to force clients to deliver a client certificate:

```
<Location /SSLTest/>
        SSLVerifyClient require
        SSLVerifyDepth 2
        SSLRequireSSL
        SSLOptions +OptRenegotiate
        SSLCipherSuite HIGH
        SSLRequire %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_OU} eq "MyClientX"
</Location>
```

How can i disable this requirement to several IPs. I tried different variants with SetEnvIf like

```
SetEnvIf Remote_addr 192.168.1.46 is_internal
```

and added a `<IfDefine !is_internal>`

around the Location, but this seems to be parsed on apache startup only. Is there a way around rewrite rules?

I'm using Apache 2.2 on Linux.

Thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, can't be done.  No hooks for it.

The nearest thing would be having /SSLTest/Internal and /SSLTest/External, and rewriting /SSLTest to one or the other based on client IP.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. Those are good ideas, but kind of like only workarounds. I think i have to go with different virtualhosts for internal/external.